# How to build single doctrine-based form with Symfony command line

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

While generating doctrine based forms with:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-form
```

Symfony overrides my previously generated and edited forms, which is so wrong! :)

Does anybody know how to generate single form? It should be somethings like:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-form MODEL_NAME
```

Answer (score 6):

After generating your forms:

```
php symfony doctrine:build-form
```

You should edit your files at:

```
<project_dir>/lib/form/doctrine/<name>Form.class.php
```

This files are not replaced when you rebuild your forms. The only files that change are at:

```
<project_dir>/lib/form/doctrine/base/<name>Form.class.php
```